# Override NotMapped attribute in derived class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm working on an EF Code-First based application. I have a base class inherited by dozens of classes, each representing entities in database. The base class has a property with `[NotMapped]` attribute, that was originally required to be `[NotMapped]` for all derived classes as well.

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [NotMapped]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I've come across an entity having column name exactly as that property name, but just due to inheriting `[NotMapped]` attribute from the parent, the value doesn't get stored in database.

```
public class InheritedEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public string Message { get; set; } // This is what I want mapped
}
```

Is there any way to override the `NotMapped` behaviour just for that class, either through DataAnnotations or FluentAPI? I've tried setting `[Column()]` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I didnt think of a simple solution i.e to rename "Message" in derived class e.g. to "StatusMessage" and map it to "Message" column using [Column] attribute. This worked for me, so all good for now.

Comment: ^ That should be an answer.

Comment: BTW, in your current code, `Message` should be an override.

Comment: @Usman, this is the only way I could find to get around this, too. You should make it the answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new attribute that does what NotMapped do.

```
NotMappedPropertyAttributeConvention
```

Applies the ff to your modelBuilder configuration:

```
ConventionTypeConfiguration Ignore(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
```

First, create custom attribute.

```
public class CustomNotMappedAttribute : Attribute
{
    public CustomNotMappedAttribute()
    {
        this.Ignore = true;
    }
    public bool Ignore { get; set; }
}
```

Then, create a PropertyAttributeConvention

```
public class CustomNotMappedPropertyAttributeConvention : PropertyAttributeConfigurationConvention
{
    public override void Apply(PropertyInfo memberInfo, ConventionTypeConfiguration configuration, CustomNotMappedAttribute attribute)
    {
        if (attribute.Ignore)
        {
            configuration.Ignore(memberInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add it to the configuration conventions

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new CustomNotMappedPropertyAttributeConvention());
}
```

Your property in entitybase should be decorated with:

```
[CustomNotMapped]
```

instead of

```
[NotMapped]
```

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [CustomNotMapped]
    public virtual string Message { get; set; }
}

public class InheritedEntity : BaseEntity
{
    [CustomNotMapped(Ignore = false)]
    public override string Message { get; set; }
}
```

There you go. Your message property in your BaseEntity will be ignore except to those decorated with `[CustomNotMapped(Ignore = false)]`

Comment: Hello, is this a standard solution to this problem?